# Yii Validation For a Multiple Image Upload

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to figure out how I can change a single file uploader to a multiple file uploaded for one page and be able to handle the validation of those assets accordingly. With the following code below I am receiving this error. The only thing is its not so much a property as just the array that I need to loop over in my controller.

Getting unknown property: app\models\ModelName::REPORTS

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload

On this page I have changed my field to the following and need to figure out what to do for the rules.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'REPORTS[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'class'=>'button'])->label('Report(s)'); ?>

[['REPORTS'], 'file'],
```

Comment: did you create your variable `$REPORTS` on your **ModelName**
like this: [Uploading Multiple Files](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload#uploading-multiple-files)

Comment: Thank you for your response. After doing so Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutObject operation:
[ContentType] must be a string or an object that implements __toString(). Found bool(false).  Getting that due to the AWS SDK after submitting my form.